# How secure is my apartment's building wide wifi network using Spectrum Community Solutions?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, network-scanners

Recently my apartment moved from having individual modems (with our own router/wifi network) to this Spectrum Community Solutions building wide network. Everyone can connect to the network anywhere, it's not apartment specific although there does seem to be a router in every apartment for connection (this router also doesn't have ethernet ports which is a gripe of mine).

Everyone connects to the same network (same SSID), and same wifi password.  However, each resident then has to enter their own username and 4 digit pin (seems too short to me) to access the internet. Their website [here](https://www.spectrum.net/support/spectrum-community-solutions/spectrum-community-support/) claims

> All data is encrypted, credentials are protected, connections are
>   private and guests can’t access the private-resident network without
>   your permission. Devices on your private resident network will be able
>   to communicate with each other, but no other resident user will be
>   able to “see” your devices.

Now I'm no security expert, but if two people happen to be connected to the same router can't someone still easily implement a scan/man in the middle attack on the other computer?  Even if the data is encrypted, I don't see how they could prevent a scan of the connected devices by a malicious individual.

As a bonus question, their brochure says not to connect my own Access point but I just tried connecting a router to their big switch box they installed in my closet.  Internet worked although i still had to sign into their login page with my 4 digit pin.  Do they have a remote way of knowing if I am using an additional port on their switch?

Comment: You'll have to ask if this is using "WPA2 Enterprise" or not.

Comment: After a brief google search of WPA2 Enterprise, it looks like WPA2 enterprise involves the additional step of individual username/pwd to access internet.  Since Spectrum's network does require this, does that mean it's Enterprise?

Comment: Most likely it's not enterprise then. Are you using a VPN supplied by them? If you aren't using that either, then I can't imagine how the connection is protected from someone who knows the Wi-Fi password and is in range, assuming it's using standard WPA2 Personal.

Comment: No no vpn, although i could get my own I suppose.  Sounds like the solution is either vpn, connect my own router to their switch and hope they don't notice, or...move out.

Comment: Looks like it. I'm refraining from answering because I don't know the details about your specific apartment's setup, but from what you've said, it does seem very much like you'd need a VPN to protect from other users on the network who know the Wi-Fi password.